# Do you always design with keyboard accessibility in mind?

Tags: accessibility, usability-engineering

How often do you design with keyboard accessibility in mind? How often is it implemented in the final product?

Comment: Do you mean the "need" for the keyboard in building the product?!

Comment: I mean considering the use of a product using just the keyboard.

Comment: Can you explain specifically what problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design no, implementation yes. Well structured HTML laid out in a logical fashion should cover a lot of the basics with regards to keyboard navigation. It maybe necessary to add a few tabIndex to elements to let the user tab to certain sections of a webpage, but there is no way/need to show this on a mockup.

Comment: How do you communicate this to the developers?

Comment: If something which isn't normally keyboard operable is intended to be keyboard operable, then that must be conveyed to the developer, with an explanation of why. This is easy to show this on a mockup; just include a note which says so, and point to whatever it is. Don't forget to explain what it should do when activated.